# cannot import name 'BatchNormalization' from 'keras.layers.normalization'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, batch-normalization

I'm learning ObjectDetection from [this website](https://www.javatpoint.com/object-recognition-using-python)

I have installed ImageAI,Tensorflow and Keras.

Then when I run this in python

```
    from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
```

I got

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/home/carl/python-environments/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/imageai/Detection/**init**.py", line 17, in 
from imageai.Detection.YOLOv3.models import yolo_main, tiny_yolo_main
File "/home/carl/python-environments/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/imageai/Detection/YOLOv3/models.py", line 8, in 
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
ImportError: cannot import name 'BatchNormalization' from 'keras.layers.normalization' (/home/carl/python-environments/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/layers/normalization/**init**.py)

Already tried:

```
    from keras.layers.normalization.batch_normalization import BatchNormalization
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
```

But still gave me the same error.

Comment: what is your tensorflow version

Comment: I installed tensorflow 2.5.0 because 2.4.0 doesn't support python3.9.

Comment: Have a look at this [tensorflow 2.8.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization)

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow v2.8.0 support tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
```